# Make UITextView clickable in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextview

I have a `UITextView` in my tableview cells, but in order to click a cell I have to click around the textview, which is not ideal. I have `selectable` and `userInteractionEnabled` on the textview so I am not sure why that is not working, what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Wait, do you just want the keyboard to automatically show?  Then you can use something like this in your ViewDidLoad for that view.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    textField.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

Or is it that you have to click around to find the right area in the TextView to launch the keyboard?  Then I would look and see if there's something in the way.  Sometimes views move around if the constraints aren't set properly.  Also the order of buttons, labels, views in your storyboard document outline can affect what is on top.